# Angular custom folder

Tags: angular

1. Is there a way to add a custom folder under assets folder in Angular. I tried creating a new folder in eclipse under assets but it is not included in the build.
2. Is there a way to add resource location to c drive in angularjs.

I am a newbie in Angular.js and would appreciate any help with the above questions

Comment: are you talking about angular or angularjs/

Comment: angular. Apologize for wrong tag

Comment: Please explain your build process. What you're trying to do is undoubtedly possible, but the answer is completely dependent on your toolchain. One thing is certain however, it has _nothing_ to do with Eclipse.

Comment: I am using eclipse to do a build. I have a webapp which has some web pages. Here is the link which I downloaded and worked on https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity

Answer (score 0):

You can add folder to build path in angular.json file

build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/images",
              "src/favicon.ico",
               Yor custom folder path
            ],

You can add custom folder path in assets array in build configuration